# What is Header Search Path in Xcode 4.3? How to use it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to add one existing project into my new project. I have added if using "Add files to "Project".
When I'm going to import it's `.h` file in my new `.h` file. It say file not found.
I have tried to add Path for Header file in Header Search Path in Search Path. But I don't know how.

- Which path I have to add in Header Search Path?
- And What is Recursion in Header Search Path?

Comment: I didnt get your question.What do you exactly want to do? explain clearly

Comment: What is Header Search Path in Xcode? How to use it? it locate in Build Setting Tab, Under Search Path.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose u have included a third party library or files say "JSONKit" whose path is outside the project folder and have added in your project then you have to specify that particular folder path in your header search path,else you will get an error.below is an example of it

[image]

Comment: Did this help.if yes please upvote/tickmark the answer so that it can be recommended for other users