# How to set Header Search Path according to .h and .m

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, header, path

It is a very basic question, But i did not find solution...

I am trying to import a .h file from the integrated project in to my project. It says SpeechToTextModule.h  file not found

I go through these links..

[Xcode 4.2 how include one project into another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)

[What is Header Search Path in Xcode 4.3? How to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633939/what-is-header-search-path-in-xcode-4-3-how-to-use-it)

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/xcode/how-to-add-multiple-static-library-files-with-different-architectures-to-xcode

My project Architecture:

I am trying to import the "SpeechToTextModule.h" in "ViewController.h"

[image]

see the above image once .. i selected speechToText.xcodeproj then  "show in Finder" then "Get Info" i got following path

/Users/stellent/Documents/Sppech2Text/Speech2ooText/3rd Party

i placed the above path in Header Search Paths

is this correct?

I set my header search paths in both Projects and Targets also, and i tried in both recursive and non-recursive

i given all these links like below image

[image]

This is my project structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy SpeechToText Project and put it inside folder containing Speech2ooText project.
2. Now Drag and drop this (SpeechToText) project inside Speech2ooText Project.
3. Go to Build Settings of Speech2ooText--> Header Search Paths and add this path

   ${SRCROOT}/3rd Party

   ${SRCROOT}  --> it is the path to your main project (Speech2ooText in your case) and by
                  giving '/3rd Party' we are telling headers are inside this folder.

Comment: have you added path for users Header search path also...?

Comment: same path ${SRCROOT}/SpeechToText

Comment: look your folder structure plays important role here... If your Folders are like Speech2ooText(contains my speech2ooText Project)-->>>>SpeechToText (contains my speechToText project and its files)...if this is the structure..then above solution will work....

Comment: see the edited question once.. i placed an image  for my project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27623/discussion-between-babul-and-bhuxan)

Comment: that problem is solved now... But, i have lot of files in my integration.. so how can i set paths to all folders... can not we give one path to all the files..... plz see the question once again.. i have added one more image

Comment: plz say this one...its enough

Comment: if you want to avoid giving those many paths then one ugly solution is that you modify your SpeechToText project without keeping files inside  nested folder but keeping all files outside...then again drag drop this modified project again...